# I have an error with the order of the scripts but have no idea to solve it. And how to save the input into variable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, local-storage

Can anyone help? Previously my code worked but now it has this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: registerUser is not defined". I know that the problem might came from the order of the script as the registerUser itself came from the javascript at lowest, but I have little to no idea how to solve this.

This is the order of the scripts:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".login").hide();
            $(".register_li").addClass("active");

            $(".login_li").click(function(){
              $(this).addClass("active");
              $(".register_li").removeClass("active");
              $(".login").show();
               $(".register").hide();
            })

            $(".register_li").click(function(){
              $(this).addClass("active");
              $(".login_li").removeClass("active");
              $(".register").show();
               $(".login").hide();
            })
        });
    </script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document
var objPeople = [
    {
        email: "sam",
        password: "password23"
    },
    {
        email: "matt",
        password: "password88"
    },
    {
        email: "chris",
        password: "password3"
    },
]   

function login(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value


for(i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++){
    if(email == objPeople[i].email && password == objPeople[i].password){
        console.log(email + " is logged in!!!")
        return
    }
}
    
console.log("incorrect email or password")
}

function registerUser(){
    var registerEmail = document.getElementById("newEmail").value
    var registerPassword = document.getElementById("newPassword").value 
    var newUser = {
        email: registerEmail,
        password: registerPassword
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i = objPeople.length; i++){
        if(registerEmail == objPeople[i].email){
            alert("that email is already been taken, please choose another!")
            return
        }
        else if(registerPassword.length < 8){
            alert("that password is too short, include 8 or more characters")
            return
        }
    }
    
    objPeople.push(newUser)
    console.log(objPeople)
}
```

This is where the registerUser is called:

```
    <div class="register">
      <div class="input_field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input_field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" id="newEmail" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input_field">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="newPassword" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="btn" onclick="registerUser()"><a href="#">Register</a></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="login">
      <div class="input_field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" id="email" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="input_field">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="input">
      </div>
      <div class="btn" onclick="login()"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
    </div>
```

In addition what is the function to make the email and password I input into the register will be saved inside the var objPeople without losing the information when reloading the page?
Thank you for reading and I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: in this line `for(int i = 0; i = objPeople.length; i++){` `int` is not valid in javascript you get a `SyntaxError` message, you could use insted `let`

Comment: check this: for(int i = 0; i = objPeople.length; i++) you assign objPeople.length to int? i.

Comment: I'm using dreamweaver and it said that i is not defined and I think there is problem without adding any. I will try using let

Comment: @Mario I have try but still face the same problem

Comment: In the code you share, you do not show where `registerUser` is called, please show where the call is made

Comment: @Mario I have added it just now

Comment: In the same line `for(int i = 0; i = objPeople.length; i++){` please fix `i = objPeople.length` for `i < objPeople.length`

Comment: In this link https://jsfiddle.net/0yfoc73u/ I have reproduced your example, please take a look. After correcting what I have commented above, it is fine. The only thing that occurs to me now is that you are not calling the script that contains the `login` and `registerUser` functions. For example if you change the name of the `registerUser` function in fiddle you will get the error you report in your question

Comment: See the working solution below and some helpful explanation for you to save data on page refresh. Cheers.

Comment: @Mario Thank you for helping. Indeed I feel that it didn't call the function for some reason. I thought it was because the order of the scripts.

Comment: @GerryGiovan The order of the scripts does not matter as long as they are in same file. You can put your function anywhere in the file and it will be called.